# Sourcing ~/.bashrc fixed PATH problem but messes up UP arrow to get past commands

Tags: command-line, bash

I added this line for a CS course I'm taking

```
export PATH=$PATH:/u/wbcowan/gnuarm4.0.2/libexec/gcc/armelf/4.0.2:/u/wbcowan/gnuarm-4.0.2/arm-elf/bin
```

to the end of my `~/.profile` so I wouldn't have to manually type in every time.

I tried `source ~/.profile`, but it didn't work, so I tried `source ~/.bashrc` which got it working.

The thing is whenever I press on my Up arrow to get past commands, the text is wacky after ~10 presses.

For example,

```
make cleavi ~/.profile
make cleasource ~/.profile
make cleacd-
```

There's only 1 line in my `.bashrc` file:

```
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

Edit:

The output of ~/.profile is

```
# WARNING: For help understanding this file, and before you try
# to change any of it, type "man .profile" and read carefully.
#

#
# Set command search rules
#
if [ -x /bin/showpath ] ; then
    export PATH; PATH=`/bin/showpath /u/wbcowan/gnuarm-4.0.2/libexec/gcc/arm-elf/4.0.2 /u/wbcowan/gnuarm-4.0.2/arm-elf/bin standard`
#
# Find out what kind of terminal we are using
#
    eval `setterm -x default:vt100`
#
# Set terminal-type dependent options (e.g. sysline or prompt string)
#
    #HOMEHOST="<hostname>"
    #HOMEUSER="<userid>"
    #export HOMEHOST HOMEUSER
    PS1="`\setprompt`"
#
# Now do the usual signing on things
#
    export MAIL; MAIL=${MAIL-"/usr/spool/mail/$USER"}

    if [ -r /software/.admin/bins/bin/read_system_news ] ; then /software/.admin/bins/bin/read_system_news ; fi
fi

export MAIL; MAIL=${MAIL-"/usr/spool/mail/$USER"}
alias g++14="g++-5 -std=c++14"
alias vi="vi -X"
export EDITOR=vi
export PATH=$PATH:/u/wbcowan/gnuarm-4.0.2/libexec/gcc/arm-elf/4.0.2:/u/wbcowan/gnuarm-4.0.2/arm-elf/bin
```

The output of `~/.bashrc` is

```
# This is an empty file. Older xhier/solaris dependant versions of this file
# in the share directory should NOT be used!
shopt -s checkwinsize
```

`echo "$PS1"` gives `\W$`

Thanks!

Comment: please paste the content of `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` .. FYI you can display the commands history with `history` and with `cat ~/.history`

Comment: also please show us the output of `echo "$PS1"`

Comment: What is `setprompt`? I suspect that your prompt is not properly escaping control sequences: see for example [Why is my bash prompt getting bugged when I browse the history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/why-is-my-bash-prompt-getting-bugged-when-i-browse-the-history)

Comment: An empty `~/.bashrc`? This isn’t Ubuntu, is it?

Comment: Hmm. I have to ssh into the school environment. I think it's Ubuntu as when I do "uname -a", it gives out "Linux ubuntu1604-004 4.4.0-121-generic #145-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 13 13:47:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
"